# How to save my links from BeautifulSoup in a text file with python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm learning python and webscraping, It is very cool but I am not able to get what I want.
I'm trying to save products links in a text file to **scrape** data after.
here is my script, which work correctly (almost) in the console of pycharm :

```
import bs4 as bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

suffixeUrl = '_puis_nblignes_est_200.html'
for i in range(15):
    url = 'https://www.topachat.com/pages/produits_cat_est_micro_puis_rubrique_est_w_boi_sa_puis_page_est_' + str(i) + suffixeUrl
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    if response.ok:
        print('Page: ' + str(i))

    for data in soup.find_all('div', class_='price'):
        for a in data.find_all('a'):
            link = (a.get('href'))
            links = ('https://www.topachat.com/' + link)
            print(links) #for getting link
```

My goal is to save the result of the links variable, line by line in a text file.
I tried this, but something is wrong and I can't get each url :

```
            for link in links:
                with open("urls.txt", "a") as f:
                    f.write(links+"\n")
```

Please, does someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way.

Just open the file once and write the complete data to it. Opening and closing files inside a loop is not a good thing to do.

```
import bs4 as bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

suffixeUrl = '_puis_nblignes_est_200.html'
with open('text.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(15):
        url = 'https://www.topachat.com/pages/produits_cat_est_micro_puis_rubrique_est_w_boi_sa_puis_page_est_' + str(i) + suffixeUrl
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        if response.ok:
            print('Page: ' + str(i))

        for data in soup.find_all('div', class_='price'):
            for a in data.find_all('a'):
                link = 'https://www.topachat.com/' + a.get('href')
                f.write(link+'\n')
```

Sample output from `text.txt`

```
https://www.topachat.com/pages/detail2_cat_est_micro_puis_rubrique_est_w_boi_sa_puis_ref_est_in11020650.html
https://www.topachat.com/pages/detail2_cat_est_micro_puis_rubrique_est_w_boi_sa_puis_ref_est_in10119254.html
https://www.topachat.com/pages/detail2_cat_est_micro_puis_rubrique_est_w_boi_sa_puis_ref_est_in20005046.html
https://www.topachat.com/pages/detail2_cat_est_micro_puis_rubrique_est_w_boi_sa_puis_ref_est_in20002036.html
https://www.topachat.com/pages/detail2_cat_est_micro_puis_rubrique_est_w_boi_sa_puis_ref_est_in20002591.html
https://www.topachat.com/pages/detail2_cat_est_micro_puis_rubrique_est_w_boi_sa_puis_ref_est_in20004309.html
https://www.topachat.com/pages/detail2_cat_est_micro_puis_rubrique_est_w_boi_sa_puis_ref_est_in20002592.html
https://www.topachat.com/pages/detail2_cat_est_micro_puis_rubrique_est_w_boi_sa_puis_ref_est_in10089390.html

.
.
.
```

Comment: Hi @Ram ! Thank you very much, it work now!!
Just a last thing, I have this message at the end  : 
``` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\PycharmProjects\test.py", line 18, in <module>
    f.write(links+"\n")
NameError: name 'links' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: My code has ```f.write(link + '\n')```. It's ```link``` not ```links```. Please check. Also upvote and accept if it works. :)

Comment: You're right, I just forgot to remove my last line :D
I tried to vote, but I don't have enough "reputation" so it did'nt worked, sorry :/
I have still a question, the page 0 and the page 1 share the same content for the 50 first entries. How can I avoid the page 1? I'd like to go from 0 to 2 , 3, 4, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
import bs4 as bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

suffixeUrl = '_puis_nblignes_est_200.html'
url_list = set()
for i in range(15):
    url = 'https://www.topachat.com/pages/produits_cat_est_micro_puis_rubrique_est_w_boi_sa_puis_page_est_' + str(i) + suffixeUrl
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    if response.ok:
        print('Page: ' + str(i))

    for data in soup.find_all('div', class_='price'):
        for a in data.find_all('a'):
            link = (a.get('href'))
            links = ('https://www.topachat.com/' + link)
            print(links) #for getting link
            url_list.add(links)


with open("urls.txt", "a") as f:
    for link in url_list:
        f.write(link+"\n")
```

Comment: Thank you it work better but I have a big problem : each link is wrote about 110 times!
Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: It might because of you're opening file in append mode, and every time you run the script it will add the data in existing file. Also the page 0 and page 1 has same content. Check this links [https://www.topachat.com/pages/produits_cat_est_micro_puis_rubrique_est_w_boi_sa_puis_page_est_0__puis_nblignes_est_200.html] [https://www.topachat.com/pages/produits_cat_est_micro_puis_rubrique_est_w_boi_sa_puis_page_est_1__puis_nblignes_est_200.html] 
If you want to add unique urls to the file, you can use set(). Check the code now. I've updated it. @Val-55

Comment: Hey @Kaushal Panchal, thank you for your help! 
Unfortunately I tried your new code but I have the same problem about the repeating lines :/
I'm trying to understand the "logic"of the problem

Comment: Can you try removing the file and run the code again? In my case it's all unique urls that are getting stored in file. If you can also attach the output file, that would be great and helpful in further debugging. @Val-55

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `for link in links` line:

```
        link = (a.get('href'))
        links = ('https://www.topachat.com/' + link)
        print(links) 

        for link in links:
            with open("urls.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(links+"\n")
```

Type of `links` is string and your for loop iterates it letter-by-letter (or characater-by-character). That is why you see a single character at each line in your txt file. You can just remove the for loop and the code will work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

suffixeUrl = '_puis_nblignes_est_200.html'
for i in range(15):
    url = 'https://www.topachat.com/pages/produits_cat_est_micro_puis_rubrique_est_w_boi_sa_puis_page_est_' + str(i) + suffixeUrl
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    if response.ok:
        print('Page: ' + str(i))

    for data in soup.find_all('div', class_='price'):
        for a in data.find_all('a'):
            link = (a.get('href'))
            links = ('https://www.topachat.com/' + link)
            print(links) #for getting link
            with open("urls.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(links+"\n")
```

Comment: Hello @Tuqay , thank for your help! I tried with your code, but I still have a problem :
each line is repeated about 100 times. How can I avoid it?